# Where can I find many Delphi 7 packages?

Tags: delphi, installation, package

For my program for auto installing Delphi 7 packages I need to find about 50 packages (for testing required time to install them to the palette). Maybe someone have many packages in archive and can upload it to the free file hosting or FTP server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[delphi super page delphi 7 section](http://delphi.icm.edu.pl/newl/d70.htm)

Answer (score 5):

There are a bunch of good sites to find free Delphi components.  One of the bigger ones is [Torry's Delphi Pages](http://www.torry.net/).